# How to give a "quick proof" of properties of the Hecke-operators?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

In "Analytic Number Theory" by Kowalski, Iwaniec p. 370 the authors prove a formula for the Fourier-coefficients of the Hecke-operators. Namely: If $$T(n) f(z) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{ad = n} a^k \sum_{0 \leq b < d } \sum_m a_f(m) e\left( m \frac{az+b}{d} \right) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty b(m)e(mz)$$
is the Hecke operator $T(n)$ applied to a weight $k$ modular form $f = \sum_{n\geq 0} c(n) e(nz)$ (let's assume, contrary to the book, that $f$ is a modular form over the full modular group), then the formula derived for $b(m)$ then is $$\sum_{d \mid (m, n)} d^{k-1} c\left( \frac{mn}{d^2}\right)$$

The authors then state that this can be used to "give [a] quick proof" of $$T(n) T(m) = \sum_{d \mid (m, n)} d^{k - 1} T\left( \frac{mn}{d^2} \right)$$
I've tried to do the proof using that the Fourier-coefficients determine a modular form. But I got only long expressions for the Fourier coefficients of the LHS and the RHS, and couldn't really conclude anything. So my question is: How can I prove this quickly using the fomula for the Fourier-coefficients?

Thanks!

**Added:** I've had the following idea: One can prove that the cusp-forms have a basis of normalized eigenforms. For eigenforms one can derive the desired formula by our expression of the Fourier-coefficients (which happen to be the eigenvalues of the eigenforms), which then holds for the whole space of cusp-forms. However, showing that the space of cusp-forms has a basis of normalized eigenforms is not a quick proof. I still think I'm missing something here...

Comment: It may be easiest just to use those special upper-triangular representatives for the Hecke operators' action, and see what they do to individual exponential functions $z \to e^{2\pi inz}$.

Comment: yes, I know that proof. I think that's even what Hecke did in his original paper. But I just thought that there might be another way via the Fourier-coefficients.

Comment: Just to clarify: I've looked it up, it's not exactly how Hecke proved the assertion in his originial paper.

Comment: Here's the same approach by me using Fourier coefficients: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821347/how-to-prove-t-mt-n-sum-d-gcdm-ndk-1t-mn-d2-t-n-is-hecke/2843374#2843374

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the "quick proof" that Iwaniec and Kowalski are referring to is probably the same as in Iwaniec's *Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms*, Theorem 6.6, pg. 96, which uses upper-triangular representatives of the action of the Hecke operators.

But looking into your initial approach involving expanding the LHS and RHS expressions of Fourier coefficients, here is what I think is an alternative combinatorial proof (which I have not seen in the literature).

Let $f(z) = \sum_{l \geq 0} c(l) e(lz)$ be the Fourier expansion of our modular form.  We know that
$$T(m)f(z) = \sum_{l \geq 0} \sum_{e|(l,m)} e^{k-1} c\left(\frac{lm}{e^2}\right) e(lz).$$
Therefore,
$$T(n)T(m)f(z) = \sum_{l \geq 0} \sum_{d|(l,n)} \sum_{e|(ln/d^2,m)} (de)^{k-1} c\left(\frac{lmn}{(de)^2}\right) e(lz).$$

On the other hand,
$$\sum_{d|(m,n)} d^{k-1} T\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right) f(z) = \sum_{l \geq 0} \sum_{d|(m,n)} \sum_{e|(mn/d^2,l)} (de)^{k-1} c\left(\frac{lmn}{(de)^2}\right) e(lz).$$

So to show that both these expressions are equal to each other, we need to prove the following proposition:

**Proposition** *Let $l,m,n$ be positive integers, and let $F$ be a function on the positive integers. Then*
$$\sum_{d|(l,n)} \sum_{e|(ln/d^2,m)} F(de) = \sum_{d|(m,n)} \sum_{e|(mn/d^2,l)} F(de).$$

For this we'll need the following lemma:

**Lemma** *Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative integers, and let $f$ be a function on the nonnegative integers.  Let*
$$G(a,b,c) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\min(a,b)} \sum_{j = 0}^{\min(a+b-2i,c)} f(i+j).$$
*Then $G(a,b,c)$ is symmetric with respect to $a,b,c$, i.e.*
$$G(a,b,c) = G(a,c,b) = G(b,a,c) = G(b,c,a) = G(c,a,b) = G(c,b,a).$$

**Proof of Lemma**  Let $\operatorname{med}(a,b,c)$ denote the median of $a,b,c$.  Write
$$G(a,b,c) = \sum_{k \geq 0} m(k) f(k).$$
A rather tedious case-by-case calculation shows that (and assuming I didn't make an error somewhere):
$$m(k) = \begin{cases}
k+1 & \text{if } k \leq \min(a,b,c),\\
\min(a,b,c)+1 & \text{if } \min(a,b,c) \leq k \leq \operatorname{med}(a,b,c),\\
\max(0,\min(a,b,c)+1+\operatorname{med}(a,b,c)-k) & \text{if } \operatorname{med}(a,b,c) \leq k \leq \max(a,b,c),\\
\max(0,a+b+c+1-2k) & \text{if } k \geq \max(a,b,c),\\
\end{cases}$$
In particular, we see that the expression for $m(k)$ is symmetric in $a,b,c$.

**Proof of Proposition**  We can apply the Lemma to prove the Proposition for prime powers:
$$\sum_{d|(p^a,p^c)} \sum_{e|(p^ap^c/d^2,p^b)} F(de) = \sum_{d|(p^b,p^c)} \sum_{e|(p^bp^c/d^2,p^a)} F(de).$$
The extension to the general case is straightforward.

If someone else can come up with a slicker proof of the Lemma or the Proposition (something better than just checking cases), I'd love to see it.

Comment: Here's the same approach by me using Fourier coefficients: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821347/how-to-prove-t-mt-n-sum-d-gcdm-ndk-1t-mn-d2-t-n-is-hecke/2843374#2843374, I bypass the lemma and prove the proposition directly. I was not aware of this when I wrote my answer.